# File naming conventions for unittesting files

Tags: python, unit-testing

For python unit tests, is the following a common naming convention?

```
MyProject/
    run_ingest.py
    tests/
        run_ingest.py
```

Or is this too redundant? If so, what would be a better naming convention or directory structure to put testing code?

Answer (score 5):

Having a directory called tests is correct but, as per my experience, the test scripts themselves are usually prefixed with `test_` so in your case `test_run_ingest.py`. Make sure to use underscore rather than `-` as a separator in the names to avoid import problems. As for the structure, you'd also probably want to include `__init__.py` files both to the top level and `/tests` folder to simplify imports.

To extend your example:

```
MyProject/
    __init__.py
    run_ingest.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_run_ingest.py
```

If you are new to `unittest` [this blog](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/07/python-3-testing-an-intro-to-unittest) might be of interest.

Comment: I have a weird bug. I have several files called `test_routes_nameofroute.py` but I wanted to make a new test suite called `test_jobs_database.py` and for some dumb reason I get an entire segfault and the tests will not run. It's only once I rename to `test_routes_database.py` that it works. What gives??

Answer (score 0):

To add to the currently top but unaccepted answer, the python.org documentation for the unittest module indicates that the default filename pattern matcher for the module's test discovery feature is "test*.py".

A basic normal way to run unittest tests to automatically 'discover' test files with that filename pattern matcher is with `python -m unittest discover`.

Normal usage for running tests with the module includes specifying other pattern matcher strings as input arguments.  Specifying a different pattern matcher looks like `python -m unittest discover -p 'unusual_test_filenames*.py`.

Here is a link to the unittest module documentation about test discovery on python.org about [unittest #test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest-test-discovery) for reference.